# xCode error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: ios, xcode

So I am trying to change my application directory (I moved my project in new folder) and this error occurred. I tried to clean and rebuild my project, restart xCode and mac, nothing helps. Looks like the problem is that I need to update old path somewhere, but I don't know where exactly.

Error stack:

```
ld: file not found: /Users/panich/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BuildingLoyalty-ezexzzfxemzfmsfdygvetpstlugg/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/BuildingLoyalty.app/BuildingLoyalty
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

My project name - BuildingLoyalty. The error is also connected with BuildingLoyaltyTests. Thx.

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Do you get this error on your BuildingLoyaltyTests only or in both targets ??

Comment: only in BuildingLoyaltyTests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to your Project, then select your Test target, then under Testing clear the values of Debug and Release like this

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should try to delete your DerivedData folder.
In your case, it seems to be located here : /Users/panich/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData